# Wordpress Upload directory to external folder or site's parant folder . how to?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having an issue with wordpress upload folder... i don't know if it was discussed here before....

i am running three sites under one domain like

```
01.mydomain.com
02.mydomain.com
03.mydomain.com
```

All these sites are having there own installation directories under the main domain like

```
mydomain.com/site01
mydomain.com/site02
mydomain.com/site03
```

Now the problem is..... each site uploads its files in its own directory.... and i want all of them to upload in one directory, in the main directory ... which is parent.

```
mydomain.com/files
```

So that the files should used anywhere in sites.... and the link to the files will be easier to remember.... and some other purposes....

I am sorry if unclear.... please let me know if so....

Comment: You should probably do a multisite installation.

Comment: Multisite is probably the good solution but right know i cant do any thing with the installation.... i have to do something with current installations.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael suggests, I would use WP's multisite function.

Then you could change the constant `WP_CONTENT_URL`.

> The upload URL path is set either by the 'upload_url_path' option or
>   by using the 'WP_CONTENT_URL' constant and appending '/uploads' to the
>   path.

You can read more about [wp_upload_dir](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir) over at wordpress.org

You can also try the solution posted here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-file-upload-folders-on-wordpress-30-multi-site

> I digged and digged for hours and finally I found out how to take
>   ultimate control over upload folders.
>
> Whenever WP is about to save an upload, it runs the wp_upload_dir()
>   function stored in wp-includes/functions.php. This function provides a
>   filter for changing whatever you like - including the upload
>   directory.
>
> I used this to make individual per user upload folders:

```
add_filter('upload_dir', 'ml_media_upload_dir');

/**
 * Changes the upload directory to what we would like, 
 * instead of what WordPress likes.
 */
function ml_media_upload_dir($upload) {
    global $user_ID;
    if ((int)$user_ID > 0) {
        $upload['subdir'] = "/" . $user_ID;
        $upload['path'] .= $upload['subdir'];
        $upload['url'] .= $upload['subdir'];
    }

    return $upload;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer..... I really liked ..... Multisite is probably the good solution... but i have to do something with my current installation and cant reinstall all my data and settings and customizations.... thanks again.... :) .... Please tell me if you could suggest something in this condition....

Comment: That should not be a problem. Install WP, enable Multisite and install any plugins you are using. Then create 3 new sites and make sure they are up and running. Once you've done that, just export the data from existing sites and import them into the Multisite. There will always be some manual job / configuration when importing / exporting data from one site to another. But once it is in place, it will make things easier for you. I strongly suggest you read up on how WP and how it's put together. If this kind of solved your problem, please up-vote and then select the `V` to accept the answer.